# Is it possible and how can I create a discount coupon via webapi or graphql natively?

Tags: discount, coupon

I found this here in the documentation but I don't know where the value or type of discount goes, whether percentage or fixed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create coupon code using API try below code.

```
// Example of defining a custom API endpoint to create a discount coupon

// YourVendor/YourModule/etc/webapi.xml
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route url="/V1/discount/coupon" method="POST">
        <service class="YourVendor\YourModule\Api\CouponManagementInterface" method="createCoupon"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>

// YourVendor/YourModule/Api/CouponManagementInterface.php
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Api;

interface CouponManagementInterface
{
    /**
     * Create a discount coupon
     *
     * @param string $couponCode
     * @param float $discountAmount
     * @param string $discountType
     * @param int $expiryDate
     * @return string
     */
    public function createCoupon($couponCode, $discountAmount, $discountType, $expiryDate);
}

// YourVendor/YourModule/Model/CouponManagement.php
<?php

namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Model;

use YourVendor\YourModule\Api\CouponManagementInterface;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\CouponFactory;

class CouponManagement implements CouponManagementInterface
{
    protected $couponFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CouponFactory $couponFactory
    ) {
        $this->couponFactory = $couponFactory;
    }

    public function createCoupon($couponCode, $discountAmount, $discountType, $expiryDate)
    {
        // Logic to create a coupon code and configure discount rules
        // Example: Generate unique coupon code and set discount amount, type, and expiry date
        $coupon = $this->couponFactory->create();
        $coupon->setCode($couponCode);
        $coupon->setType($discountType);
        $coupon->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
        $coupon->setExpirationDate($expiryDate);
        $coupon->save();

        return $couponCode;
    }
}
```

Use cerated API as per the below code OR you can use Postman.

```
<?php

$endpoint = 'http://yourmagento.com/rest/V1/discount/coupon';
$accessToken = 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN'; // Optional if your API endpoint requires authentication
$couponCode = 'YOUR_COUPON_CODE';
$discountAmount = 10.00; // Example discount amount
$discountType = 'fixed'; // Example discount type (can be 'fixed' or 'percent')
$expiryDate = strtotime('+1 month'); // Example expiry date (1 month from now)

$data = [
    'couponCode' => $couponCode,
    'discountAmount' => $discountAmount,
    'discountType' => $discountType,
    'expiryDate' => $expiryDate,
];

$ch = curl_init($endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken, // Optional if your API endpoint requires authentication
]);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Let me know if any queries.

**`Thanks.`**